# Run a powershell command as administrator in a bat file

Tags: powershell

I have this powershell command that must run as administartor in powershell. I want to run as a batch file as administator. Would you please help me?

Get-AppxPackage -allusers *ContentDeliveryManager* | foreach {Add-AppxPackage "$($_.InstallLocation)\appxmanifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode -register }

Answer (score 0):

You can run it like this:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ""& {Get-AppxPackage -allusers ContentDeliveryManager | foreach {Add-AppxPackage ""$($_.InstallLocation)\appxmanifest.xml"" -DisableDevelopmentMode -register }"" -Verb RunAs}"
```

**UPDATE**

Fixed double quotes

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problem of double/double quote, i suggest you to put your command in a `script.ps1` then do this command:

```
PowerShell -windowstyle hidden -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -windowstyle hidden -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""YourScript.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this batch

```
<# : batch script
@echo off
cd /D "%~dp0"
if not "%1"=="am_admin" (powershell start -verb runas '%0' am_admin & exit /b)
setlocal
cd %~dp0
powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned -Command "Invoke-Expression $([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('%~f0'))"
endlocal
goto:eof
#>
# here write your powershell commands...
Get-AppxPackage -allusers ContentDeliveryManager | foreach {Add-AppxPackage "$($_.InstallLocation)\appxmanifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode -register }
```

save it as .bat or .cmd and run it.